# Understanding Pandas probability density plot

Tags: pandas

When plotting a pandas DataFrame as a probability density function, how is the y-axis computed? It is clear that the higher the number is on the y-axis, the more data is represented, but I don't understand the calculation that determines the height of the plot. Below is an example.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess you're plotting a histogram?

Comment: @miradulo i'm just plotting as `kind='density'` so just a continuous distribution rather than a histogram.

Comment: You should post your code so we can see what you're trying to do.